# I am trying to make a bunch of ascii characters move, but they only move together as one group. Why is that? (C#)

Tags: c#, class

I've been trying to figure out as to why my ascii people won't move independently as one figure, as they've been moving as one group.
My goal is to make a bunch of guys move in four random directions every frame. Every person is a class with it's own set of data, like the X and Y position of them. Here is a part of the code:

What the code does by the way, is it spawns 10 people in a rectangle of 10x2. This is when the problem arises.

```
public class Soldier
    {
        public int Health;
        public string Symbol;
        public int x, y;
        public int ID;

        public void SetHealth(int hp)
        {
            Health = hp;
        }

        public void SetSymbol(string sym)
        {
            Symbol = sym;
        }

        public void SetID(int id)
        {
            ID = id;
        }

        public void RandomStep()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();

            int randNum = rnd.Next(1, 5);

            if (randNum == 1)
            {
                x += 1;
            }
            else if (randNum == 2)
            {
                x -= 1;
            }
            else if (randNum == 3)
            {
                y += 1;
            }
            else if (randNum == 4)
            {
                y -= 1;
            }
        }
    }

else if (battleMode == true)
                {
                    bool battleLoad = true;
                    int team1Size = 0;
                    int team1Max = 10;
                    int rowXstart = 40;
                    int rowYstart = 10;
                    int rowX = rowXstart;
                    int rowXmax = rowXstart + 5;
                    int rowY = rowYstart;
                    int rowYmax = 5;
                    int pickIDsol = 1;
                    int IDsoldier = 1;

                    int battleID = 1;

                    List<Soldier> soldierunlist = new List<Soldier>();
                    List<Soldier> soldierlist = new List<Soldier>();

                    for (; ; )
                    {
                        if (battleLoad == true)
                        {


                            for (; ; )
                            {
                                if (team1Size < team1Max)
                                {
                                    soldierunlist.Add(new Soldier());
                                    Soldier unpickSoldier = soldierunlist.First(x => x.ID == 0);
                                    unpickSoldier.ID = IDsoldier;
                                    IDsoldier += 1;
                                    team1Size += 1;
                                    Console.WriteLine("Loading1");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    break;
                                }
                            }

                            foreach (Soldier soldier in soldierunlist) {
                                soldier.Symbol = "☻";
                                Console.WriteLine("Loading Graphics");
                            }

                            for (; ; )
                            {
                                if (soldierunlist.Count != 0)
                                {
                                    if (rowX < rowXmax)
                                    {
                                        Soldier pickSoldier = soldierunlist.First(x => x.ID == pickIDsol);
                                        pickSoldier.x = rowX;
                                        pickSoldier.y = rowY;
                                        rowX += 1;
                                        pickIDsol += 1;

                                        soldierunlist.Remove(pickSoldier);
                                        soldierlist.Add(pickSoldier);
                                        Console.WriteLine("Creating Position values for soldiers");
                                    }
                                    else if (rowX >= rowXmax)
                                    {
                                        rowX = rowXstart;
                                        rowY += 1;
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    battleLoad = false;
                                    battleMode = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            for (; ; ){
                                Console.Clear();
                                int RefreshRate = 100; // 1000 = 1 second
                                /// [ START ]

                                //foreach (Soldier soldier in soldierlist)
                                //{
                                //    WriteAt(soldier.Symbol, soldier.x, soldier.y);
                                //    soldier.RandomStep();
                                //}

                                for (; ; )
                                {



                                    if (battleID != team1Max)
                                    {
                                        Soldier aSoldier = soldierlist.First(x => x.ID == battleID);
                                        aSoldier.RandomStep();
                                        battleID += 1;

                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        break;
                                    }

                                }

                                foreach (Soldier soldier in soldierlist)
                                {
                                    WriteAt(soldier.Symbol, soldier.x, soldier.y);
                                }

                                battleID = 1;

                                /// [ END ] 
                                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(RefreshRate); // Waits for (number) of time
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Why not Debug it?  Single step through your program at the point where the movement commands are issued, and see what is happening for yourself!

Comment: @khargoosh The funny thing here is that during debugging he will not see the problem - it will work fine (assuming breakpoint is at exit of `RandomStep`). Because he will pause to check the value, so the next call will not happen as fast, so there will be a different seed for `Random` => different directions of his soldiers.

Comment: @khargoosh - unfortunately, as Zizy points out, the problem is due to creating lots of `Random` instances close together temporally. Exactly the sort of problem that wouldn't show up during debugging because you're taking longer between steps.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Indeed! Of course the fact that a different result is observed during debugging vs normal execution is itself an important clue that time is the relevant factor.  Someone more familiar with RNG would have been pointed in the right direction at that point!

Comment: Okay, It's working a little. It still has the grouping problem, but at times when restarting the program again two or three would separate from the group. Is there something I might be missing? I placed the randNum outside of the method and placed it beside the line of variables inside the Soldier class.

Comment: Okay guys, it works now! Many great thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Random rnd = new Random();
```

creates a new random every time you want a random number. As all the calls will be about instant, you will end up with the same seed every time, so all move in the same direction.

From documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx):

> However, because the clock has finite resolution, using the parameterless constructor to create different Random objects in close succession creates random number generators that produce identical sequences of random numbers. ... On most Windows systems, Random objects created within 15 milliseconds of one another are likely to have identical seed values. ... To avoid this problem, create a single Random object instead of multiple objects.

So, you need to create a single random object. Maybe at the loading of the game. Then use that single random to create directions to move in, which will be then different.